# Where are the access rights stored for security roles in serialized files?

Tags: security, unicorn, serialization

When we create security roles and assign access rights, corresponding serialized files for role get created. But when we look at the files we don't see any data related to access rights. So just wanted to know where the data related to access are stored.

We are using Unicorn for serialization.

```
Role: |
  che\Approver
MemberOf:
  Role: |
    che\Editor
```

Comment: Access assignment is at the item level. When you serialize the home item, and if you changed security on it, then you should see what you expect.

Comment: For this, you can check the __Security Field, where rights are stored for an item. This is a shared field and as such will be in SharedFields table. Security information is actually a pipe delimited list.

Comment: If you still don't find, please let me know, i may provide you the sql script to get that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Security stored on items

Access rights (security) are stored on the item itself, in the `__Security` field. You can see the contents of this field in a few ways:

### Security Details tab

In the Content Editor, under the **Security** ribbon tab, click the **Details** button and you will see the following tab:

[image: Security Details tab]

### Raw field values

If you want to be able to copy the security from one item to another (or manually manipulate the security settings [not recommended]), you can show standard fields (**View** ribbon tab -> **Standard Fields**) and show raw values (**View** ribbon tab -> **Raw Values**):

[image: __Security raw values]

### Access Viewer

To see the *effective* security permissions for an item, you can use the Access Viewer (**Security** ribbon tab -> **Access Viewer**). This shows not just what security is set on the current item, but how the ancestors' security affects this item for a given user or role:

[image: Access Viewer]

Answer (score 3):

**Security** informations are stored on the item and stored in the `__Security` Field. This is a shared field and you should find it in SharedFields table.

To get the value from database, you can trigger below SQL query

```
SELECT  Id, ItemId, FieldId, Value, Created, Updated
FROM    SharedFields
WHERE   ItemId = '{A57C19C2-8EE3-4DEC-AA39-0B8D522D59EB}' AND FieldId = '{DEC8D2D5-E3CF-48B6-A653-8E69E2716641}' /* Guid is the ID of the __Security field */
```

Result

```
8AA77E96-2330-4BE1-A554-BAE9C60536FF    A57C19C2-8EE3-4DEC-AA39-0B8D522D59EB    DEC8D2D5-E3CF-48B6-A653-8E69E2716641    au|sitecore\agency|pd|-item:write|-item:admin|!*|+item:read|-item:delete|-item:create|-item:rename|pe|-item:write|-item:admin|!*|+item:read|-item:delete|-item:create|-item:rename| 2011-03-07 11:48:14.563 2011-03-07 11:48:14.563
06A6DB6C-6DEF-40E0-8CF8-8E179877DBB8    A57C19C2-8EE3-4DEC-AA39-0B8D522D59EB    DEC8D2D5-E3CF-48B6-A653-8E69E2716641    au|sitecore\agency|pd|-item:write|-item:admin|!*|+item:read|-item:delete|-item:create|-item:rename|pe|-item:write|-item:admin|!*|+item:read|-item:delete|-item:create|-item:rename| 2011-03-07 11:48:14.270 2011-03-07 11:48:14.270
```